# awk NR variable not working as expected, getting the whole line while asking for first field

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

```
echo cat:
cat Records.txt
echo ""
echo Using a digit for the second record:
record_id=$(awk 'NR==2{print $1; exit}' Records.txt)
echo $record_id
echo ""
a=2
echo a is set to $a
echo ""
echo Using a variable and single quotes:
record_id=$(awk 'NR==$a{print $1; exit}' Records.txt)
echo $record_id
echo Using a variable and double quotes:
record_id=$(awk "NR==$a{print $1; exit}" Records.txt)
echo $record_id
```

Output

```
cat:
Apples 1000 happy worms
Carrots 10 happy bunnies

Using a digit for the second record:
Carrots

a is set to 2

Using a variable and single quotes:

Using a variable and double quotes:
Carrots 10 happy bunnies
```

I understand that double quotes are needed to use a variable, but why is it nolonger confined to output of the first field only? I only want the word Carrots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use single quotes, `$a` is not expanded by the shell, so awk sees literal `NR=$a`. Since the *awk variable* `a` is uninitialized, that is equivalent to `NR=$0` which compares the current record number to the *value* of the record.

When you use double quotes, both `$a` *and* `$1` are expanded by the shell, and the expression becomes `NR==2{print ; exit}` because `$1` is  empty in your interactive shell - that's why it prints the whole record.

Here are a couple of ways to pass shell variable values to awk while avoiding the trickiness of shell expansion:

```
awk -v a="$a" 'NR==a{print $1; exit}'
```

or

```
export a
awk 'NR==ENVIRON["a"]{print $1; exit}'
```

(You *could* use double quotes to allow expansion of `$a` and then prevent expansion of `$1` by additional quoting/escaping ex. `awk "NR==$a{print \$1; exit}" Records.txt` but I recommend against it.)

Comment: That makes sense (finally). Thank you.

Comment: @Insideup Consider accepting and upvoting the answer. This is the way we say thanks at Stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use double quotes and escape the `$` in print statement for bash to ignore it as

```
awk "NR==2{print \$1; exit}"
```